# Python doesen't communicate with Arduino over Serial

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port

I was trying to send some Serial Data with python to my Arduino and light a led on/off, over the Serial monitor of the Arduino IDE it works fine but once I try to do it over the Python code, it won't work

Here is the Arduino Code:

```
int LED = 7;
char serialData;

void setup() {
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT); 
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

  serialData = Serial.read();


if(serialData == '1'){
  digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
}

if(serialData == '2'){
  digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
}

}
```

And this is the Python Code:

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial()
ser.baudrate = 9600
ser.port = 'COM5'

time.sleep(10)

ser.write("1")
```

Now what it should do when I start the python code, is to send the "1"over Serial to the Arduino, the Arduino should receive it and light on the led.

Comment: maybe you have to use `ser.flush()` to send it.

Comment: @furas nope, doesn't work either

Comment: can you try adding a delay (`delay(10)`) after `digitalWrite(LED, HIGH)` and `digitalWrite(LED, LOW)` inside their `if` statements ?

Answer (score 1):

I think your Arduino code is fine, except that you just wait until you get some input in the serial port (line `serialData = Serial.read();`). If this is intended, that is fine, but if not you should consider checking [Serial.available()](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Available).

The main issue is in the Python code. As described in the [pyserial documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/shortintro.html), you need to open the serial port. Also, you should consider closing this at the end of the code (you do not have to worry about if you use `with` to open the serial port as described [here](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shortintro.html)).

I added a `for` statement so that you can visualize the blinking on the Arduino.

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial()
ser.baudrate = 9600
ser.port = 'COM5'

ser.open()

for i in range(10):
    ser.write("1")
    time.sleep(1)
    ser.write("2")
    time.sleep(1)

ser.close()
```

Comment: that didn't work for me either, for my understanding, the python could should look like this with "with" 
```import serial
import time

with ser = serial.Serial('COM5', 9600)

ser.open()
    ser.flush()
    ser.write("1")
    time.sleep(1000)```

Comment: Nope, it should be `with open(serial.Serial('COM5', 9600)) as ser:` and no `ser.open()` after that. I ran this code on an Arduino Mega and it worked fine. What is your board? And can you report if you can just blink the LED on pin 7 from Arduino board, without Python communication?

Comment: That kinda works, I can now turn it off using the off python off code, but my other file that is exactly the same apart from the number does not affect it at all.